# Scss issue migrating from @import to @use and meta.load-css

Tags: sass

Simplified example of what I had:

main.scss

```
.a {
  .b {
    .c {
      .d {
         @import "_other";
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

_other.scss

```
&.d2 {
  ...
}
```

Apparently this was working OK.

But when trying to migrate to `@use` or `@include meta.load-css`, I get the following error:

**Top-level selectors may not contain the parent selector "&"**

What is the best way to migrate this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinionated answer is to always wrap partials in mixins to prevent CSS from being rendered out of the blue without you asking for it (using @include).

```
// ----------------
// _foo.scss
// ----------------
@mixin foo {
  .a {
    .b {
      .c {
        .d {
           @content
        } 
      }
    }
  }  
}

// ----------------
// _bar.scss
// ----------------
@mixin bar {
  &.d2 {
    ...
  }
}


// ----------------
// main.scss
// ----------------
//
// Import partials
//
@use './reset' as *;
@use './typography' as *;
@use './foo' as *;
@use './bar' as *;


//
// Assemble
//
@include reset;
@include typography; 
@include foo {
  @include bar;
}
```

If the _bar.scss is strongly related to _foo.scss (e.g. to make it more readable) you could also include it directly (then only foo would have to be included in the assemble file)

```
// ----------------
// _foo.scss
// ----------------
@use './bar' as *;
@mixin foo {
  .a {
    .b {
      .c {
        .d {
           @include bar;
        } 
      }
    }
  }  
}
```